# getting real-time buffer too full or near too full! frame dropped from ffmpeg while streaming video from camera

Tags: ffmpeg, video, windows-11, rtsp

I'm trying to stream video from my camera with RTSP protocol locally using ffmpeg but I'm getting the error:

> [dshow @ 06464c00] real-time buffer [EasyCamera] [video input] too
> full or near too full (101% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])!
> frame dropped!

I've tried increasing rtbufsize as other suggestions, increasing thread_queue_size but nothing worked. Why am I getting this error and how do I fix this?

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -thread_queue_size 1024 -f dshow -i video="EasyCamera" -video_size 640x480 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -rtbufsize 2G -r 15 -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:3030/stream
```